# Model is not injected into servlet

Tags: java, servlets, cdi

I have simple servlet project:
I need to inject dependency to a servlet instance. I tried several annotations: **Default**, **Singlton**, **EJB**, **ManagedBean**, nothing helps.

Part of POM.xml

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
          <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>

                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Servlet

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/updater_servlet"},loadOnStartup = 1)
public class Updater_servlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private final static org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Updater_servlet.class);

    @Inject
    private UpdatesModel updates;

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        ...
    }
```

Model class

```
@Model
public class UpdatesModel implements Serializable
{
    private final static org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UpdatesModel.class);

    private final String url;
    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    private final String instpath;

    public UpdatesModel()
    {
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        try
        {
            Class.forName(driverName);
            prop.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException|IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(UpdatesModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        url          = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + prop.getProperty("database","");
        username     = prop.getProperty("dbuser","");
        password     = prop.getProperty("dbpassword","");

        instpath     = prop.getProperty("instpath","");
    }
```

Updates field is never initialized. It's equals null. What I've done wrong?

UPDATE:
dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I created empty beans.xml in WEB-INF - doesn't help ((
I deploy to Tomcat 7. Also tried to tomcat 8 - no difference ((

Comment: I don't know any `@Model` annotation that works with Servlets.

Comment: So what should I use? BTW Model is javax.enterprise.inject.Model

Comment: What container are you deploying to?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the chunk of your `pom.xml` is totally irrelevant to the problem ;) The dependencies part would be more interesting.

Create or make sure it exist empty file called `beans.xml` in the `WEB-INF` directory.

Make sure you have the cdi-api dependency defined in your `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>version</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also make sure you are deploying your war into CDI enabled application server like Wildfly (JBoss) or make sure you have all necessary libraries on the classpath if it is mere servlet container like Tomcat.

It is also good practice to inject concrete implementations to interfaces, so your `UpdatesModel` class should implement some interface specifying its behavior. This is not necessary though.

EDIT: the dependency to weld is necessary only in SE environment. In EE all is needed should be `cdi-api`.

Comment: If you start a new project I suggest cloning the samples on Github. Here is something similar what you need https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/master/cdi-alternative/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/cdi/alternative/Demo.java

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to solve this issue. I added

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.10.Final</version>
 </dependency>
```

to pom.xml and created UpdaterRequestListener

```
@WebListener
public class UpdaterRequestListener extends org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener
{
}
```

I wonder if I could do that without some additional weld dependency? Is there a javax alternative?